# Python [2.7.11] user input and writing to file

Tags: python

Hello for some reason I cant get this code I am working on to just add a new line to the html document, I am new a python just started coding yesterday, I mainly work with ms-dos but that's not actaly a language.

anyhow what the code is doing is is taking user input and output to the chat.html file, i have it on a loop so people can still add words to the file, however It will replace that line of the file on every new word.

I have tried looking on YouTube for bits of code that may work as well as many forums and help docs by python, nothing seems to work for what ever reason.

Below you can find the code that I am working with, no doubt its something relay simple that I don't know about yet.

```
while 1:
    userinput = raw_input('Message:')
    myfile = open('./chat.html', 'w')
    myfile.write(userinput)
    myfile.close()
    if userinput == 'exit': break
```

Comment: Your code as posted here will not run. Please make sure you indent it precisely as it is on your computer.

Comment: try using `open('./chat.html', 'a')` otherwise you overwrite the file on each loop

Comment: The immediate problem is that opening for writing will erase the earlier contents of the file. You want to open for appending, or just not close it between writes.

Comment: @wilbur The `while 1:` body lacks any indentation. Maybe that's an empty endless loop in some version, but in the ones I have used, this was always a syntax error.

Comment: @triplee Are we looking at the same question? I edited the indentation before you commented.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just open the file outside the loop once?

```
with open('./chat.html', 'a') as myfile:
    while 1:
        userinput = raw_input('Message:')

        if userinput == 'exit':
            break

        myfile.write('{}\n'.format(userinput))
```

Closing is taken care of by using `with`

Answer (score 0):

You open file once outside the while loop and then check for the condition. Or you can open the file in append mode so that it wont overwrite the previous contents.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take advantage of the "with" keyword to open and close files. Here's how I would do it:

```
while True:
    userInput = raw_input("Message: ").lower()
    if userInput == 'exit':
        break #or sys.exit() if you want
    else:
        with open('./chat.html', 'a') as myfile:
            myfile.write(userInput)
```

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say your if/else logic is wrong

Comment: Oh. That's a stupid mistake on my part. I got ahead of myself while writing this answer out. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I think we are misunderstanding what the OP is really asking for.

He/she is asking to see if there is a solution to the issue which overwrites the contents within the "./chat.html" file for every new word he/she enters.

The easiest fix to this issue is as stated below:

```
    while 1:
        userinput = raw_input('Message:')
        if userinput == 'exit':
            exit()
        myfile = open('./chat.html', 'a')
        myfile.writelines(userinput)
        myfile.close()
```